# ¿A qué .fit() se refiere diferente de .evaluate() en Keras?

Tags: python-2.7, keras

Traté de probar una red neuronal, pero cuando termina me da los siguientes resultados:

```
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)
```

Y aparece en la pantalla :

> ```
> ...
> 142976/143613 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0490 - acc: 0
> 143168/143613 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0490 - acc: 0
> 143360/143613 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0490 - acc: 0
> 143552/143613 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0490 - acc: 0
> 143613/143613 [==============================] - 
> 45s 317us/step - loss: 0.0490 - acc: 0.9818 - val_loss: 0.0560 - val_acc: 0.9802
> 159571/159571 [==============================] - 3s 20us/step
> ```

Y cuando los escribo y los imprimo parecen bastante diferentes.

```
# Devuelve el valor de pérdida y los valores de métrica para el modelo en modo de prueba.
train_result = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, sample_weight=None, steps=None)
print "train_result\n",train_result
```

> ```
> train_result
> [0.046446133452974679, 0.98271510681591834]
> ```

Dicen en la documentacion que :

> **evaluate**
>
> `evaluate(self, x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, verbose=1, sample_weight=None, steps=None)`
>
> Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te muestra el `model.evaluate` y durante el entrenamiento son los valores para cierto `batch_size` según la iteración en que está y no los de todos los datos en train.

Por lo que estos resultados pueden ser muy diferentes según el batch size que mira la red.